# Vagrant dynamic RAM allocation in CentOS

Tags: centos, vagrant, ram, vagrantfile

At the moment I have a basic Vagrant file. How can I add to my configuration dynamic memory allocation?

Here is my code:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos7"
  config.vm.box_url = "centos-7.0-x86_64.box"

  config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
    sudo touch /home/asd.txt
    sudo yum install mc > /drv/null 2>&1"
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic memory allocation? Allocate memory on demand as needed by the guest machine? I'm afraid that can't be done. Also which provider are you using? Virtualbox?

Comment: Yes, I am using virtual box. Yes I want to allocate what I am using.

Comment: Memory allocation is fixed and static during `vagrant up`. That means, if you specify 2G memory in `Vagrantfile` then guest will take 2G memory, whether you use it inside guest or not doesn't matter. You can not modify this value on demand. For example, you can't start vagrant with 1G memory and increase/decrease it as needed while running vagrant is not possible, AFAIK.

Comment: Probably this limitation is implied by provider Virtualbox, not by Vagrant itself. I don't know whether any provider other that Virtualbox supports this.

Comment: I found this, but I dont know it is working. https://drupal.psu.edu/blog/post/dynamic-memory-allocation-vagrant-virtual-machines-windows-hosts

Comment: I haven't gone through this in detail but I don't think this is changing memory on demand since `v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem]` in Vagrantfile will only execute while upping the machine. By dynamic allocation the article probably meant just to divide total RAM by 4 (which can vary from developer to developer), but not modifying memory size on demand.